# Есть ли функция нахождения коэффициента?

Tags: sql, функции, oracle

В столбце "Оценка" находятся разделённые на 3 категории оценки:

```
1 - неудовлетворительно
2 - удовлетворительно
3 - хорошо.
```

Есть ли функция, которая выведет коэффициент неудовлетворительных оценок от общего количества оценок?

Например:

```
кол-во неуд. оценок / кол-во всех оценок       неуд.       уд.           хор.
                   0,5                             1         1              0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, такой функции нет, и вряд ли она появится. Её надо написать самому:

```
create table t (grade check (grade in (1,2,3))) as 
    select mod (rownum, 3)+1 from dual connect by level<=9 
/
select 
    to_char (grade1/grades, 'FM90D99') "коэфф. неуд. оценок", 
    grade1 "неуд.", grade2 "уд.", grade3 "хор."
from (
    select
        count (*) grades, 
        count (case grade when 1 then 1 end) grade1, 
        count (case grade when 2 then 1 end) grade2, 
        count (case grade when 3 then 1 end) grade3
    from t) t
/
```

Результат:

```
коэфф. неуд. оценок      неуд.        уд.       хор.
------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
0,33                         3          3          3
```